# Retrieving information of a subclass in a many-to-many situation (link table)

Tags: java

For a project I'm developping an application that is able to show certain information to the user. The information is stored in a database, and the application is able to mix it all together to make sense to the user.

The database is somewhat like this:

A (super)class table called `Animal` with the PK being `AnimalId`, and the column `Type`. Separate tables for each kind of animal, with their own specific columns. Each table has a PK `Id` like `HorseId`, `DogId` etc. The `AnimalId` is an FK to each of the different `Ids`. I have another table called `Owner`, with PK `OwnerName`. 
An `Owner` can have multiple animals, and animals can have multiple owners. Therefore, `AnimalId` is used in a link table `Animal_Owner`, together with `OwnerName`. The application shows a list of animals, and after one is selected by the user, the application shows the list of linked owners. This also works the other way around.
In the application, `Owner`, `Horse` etc are all model classes, with `Animal` being a superclass to the animal classes, with `Id` and `Type` being the super properties.

In the application, I try to work with collections, to minimize the calls to the database. So each time a list is initiated (list of animals for example) or the associated owners are extracted from the database, they are also stored in a Collection (`HorseCollection`, `OwnerCollection` etc). Each time specific information is required, the application first checks its Collection, and if the information is not found, it performs a call to the database and stores the information in the Collection afterwards.

The following issue is the issue I'm struggling with. When an `Owner` is selected from a list of available owners, I get an `Id` from the link table (or the associated collection), but I don't know from which animal table the `Id` actually is. I could call the database (table `Animal`) to ask which `Type` belongs to the `Id`, but that means that everytime a user selects something, I need to do a call to the database; which I wanted to avoid if possible.
I can't instantiate a Collection of `Animals` and work with the same principle as the other Collections, because it is an abstract class.

What is the correct action in this matter? Or is my approach faulty in the first place?
If you  need more information or if I'm not specific enough, please let me know.

Comment: you should use 'cache' instead of collection since this is the purpose here ;) otherwise theres no issue in querying the DB twice (once for the type, once for the attribute). Still you should also maintain a 'cache' (or collection :p) for the AnimalId > AnimalType link since you decided to keep separate cache collections for each animal type :)

Comment: I've never heard of 'cache' as an alternative to Collection as I use it, it sounds very interesting! I'm going to delve into it. Thanks!

Comment: thats was just a vocabulary convention : cache means you store locally data from a remote source so you do not need to call again in the current session :)

Comment: Oh, you mean that I can still use a Collection, but should use a different name? But then I should make a Collection of Animal, though not with Animal-objects (as Animal is an abstract class), but with a dummy-AnimalObject in which the Id -> Type are stored?
And what about the idea to make a superCollection/Cache containing the separate caches of the animal tables?